# Validate a form in backend based on the selected site language

Tags: django, validation

The problem is that for different users the same field may be required or optional to fill out in a form. How to raise an error, same as for as the one shown if the required field was not filled? I would like to raise standard validation because it already has all the translations.

P.S. I would like to validate it using backend (without HTML).

I will be pleased if you tell me an effective way of raising this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the user preferred language through `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` in your views. Regarding this value and fields which were submitted, you could then decide whether or not to raise an exception!

You could raise `ValidationError` if you pass the value of `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` to your form when instantiating it.

Comment: I can do this, but unfortunately this will not solve my problem or I don't understand something. For example, I have 2 fields for the same item: title_en and title_fr. If a person visits the site from the interface in French, then he sees the field title_fr and it must be filled out. However, the title_en field is not required to fill out for him.
I know how to raise ValidationError but I do not know how to trigger the standard validation for a required field because it already has all the translations.

Comment: Ok now I think I did understand your issue :-) Just a suggestion: why don't you use just one form, with only one `title` field (and not two)? Because I guess the point of that is to set a value for a `title_fr` or `title_en` attribute of one model instance, am I right? In your view, check the value of `request.LANGUAGE_CODE`, then you will know which attribute needs to be set (`title_fr` or `title_en`). That way, you won't have anything to do in your template or in your form (which is much better if you have 10 languages to take into account...)

Comment: If you really want to have multiple fields for each language, considerer having a form for each language maybe? Then, in your view, check `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` and set the right form to use. I think you've got plenty of ways to do that, without having to adapt your html template!

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your patience. I use language code but I need something else. There is a requirement to have the possibility to switch content and interface language on a site. It is easy to do if translations are stored in one model and all is now up and running well. I can switch language of a specific interface and content easily. If I created different models for each language, it can be difficult to associate them with each other. I have only one question: how to set the standard "required" validation using backend to only those fields that are displayed to a user in a form?

Comment: I would suggest to set the `required` attribute according to `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` in the `__init__` method of your form. It would look like something like: `if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'FR': self.fields['some_field'].required = True|False`. Would that give the expected behavior?

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for the excellent advice I will check it ASAP. I just realized what you meant. Thank you and Happy New Year!